# Execute function from String in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parameters

Is there a way to execute a function from String passed as a request parameter and return result in node.js ?
Imagine a request which contains String:

```
"db.users.find()"
```

as a parameter

If I knew I wanted to execute this statement I would do this:

```
db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
});
```

What I want is something like a parser which would execute given statement and returned results.

I tried like this:

```
exports.execStatement = function(req, res) {
//var statemnet = req.params.statement;
  var statement = "collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);});";
  db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {        
    eval(statement)
   });
};
```

This code gives me error:

```
var statement = "collection.find().toArray(function(err, prdel) { ...
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What is wrong ? Why can't I execute code stored in a String ? After this works I would like to figure out how to execute code which is passed as a parameter in request.

Is this approach even possible ?

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? Are you absolutely certain there is no other way to achieve what you need?

`eval` is evil, and a sinkhole of code-injection exploits.

Comment: I am begginer in JS. I just need to execute user defined statements on the server. Maybe there is better way to do it than eval, but I don't know about it.

Comment: User defined statements? Why, if I may ask?
Isn't it an option to build a set of predefined functionalities?

Comment: No, it is not enough to have predefined functionality. The goal is to create a kind of middleware which supplies whatever data the user might need without him connecting directly to db. User defined statements are the ultimate goal of this project.

Comment: Could you post the actual code causing the problem? The error message doesn't match the code snippet you posted.

Comment: You realize that someone could send "collection.drop()" and delete all the data in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

The second example shows how you can add a function to a db.

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#eval

However DON'T. There are three main reasons

1. In 2.2 and earlier SpiderMonkey is single threaded meaning abysmal performance for your "stored procedures"
2. An eval requires a write lock for the duration of the operation (unless you specifically set nolock and then you better not write or it will fail). This stops all write operations on the db until your function finishes executing.
3. Injection attacks but that's been covered above.